# Globally define parts of virtualhost definition to reduce redundancy

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have setup an apache server and this apache server points to a bunch of virtualhosts.

The definition of the virtualhosts are as follows,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName <url>

        RewriteEngine on
        ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

        # Enable client-side caching of resources
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 48 hours"

</VirtualHost>

.
.
.

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName <url>

        RewriteEngine on
        ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

        # Enable client-side caching of resources
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType image/png "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType image/gif "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType application/javascript "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType text/javascript "now plus 48 hours"
        ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 48 hours"

</VirtualHost>
```

I have a ton of virtual host definitions similar to the examples shown above.

Since, most of the definitions other than the `ServerName` are the same, I was wondering if there was a way to define these common definitions globally.

I am new to apache configuration and I felt that as the number of virtualhost definitions increase my configuration file becomes longer and redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a few options. First, depending on the directive you want to use, it might be something you can add at the server level.

Second, there's a module called [mod_macro](http://people.apache.org/~fabien/mod_macro/) that is specifically for this use case. You can define a single macro for your virtual hosts:

```
<Macro VHost $host $port $dir>
  Listen $port
  <VirtualHost *:$port>
    ServerName $host
    DocumentRoot $dir

    <Directory $dir>
      # do something here...
    </Directory>

    # etc etc etc

  </VirtualHost>
</Macro>
```

and then call it like this:

```
Use VHost www.apache.org 80 /projects/apache/web
```

You could also declare a macro just for your `Exipres` directives, and include it by calling

```
Use ExpireMacro
```

inside your virtual host.

I use `mod_macro` and it works great, it's a terrific way to simplify your apache config.

EDIT: I should mention, unless the module is already on your server, you'll need to compile it and install it, which means you'll need root access.

Comment: I downloaded and extracted the "mod_macro-1.2.1" from the document you shared with me.
I extracted it and performed "apxs -cia /mod_macro.c", this gave me the following error cannot open /usr/lib64/httpd/build/config_vars.mk: No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/apxs line 201.

Comment: to overcome this I yum installed "apr-devel" and "httpd-devel" and I am still encountering errors. By any chance do you know of any other way to install mod_macro?

Comment: Looks ike it might be available as an RPM --s see http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=apache-mod_macro otherwise can you  let me know the actual errors?

Comment: "warning: /root/apache-mod_macro-1.1.11-3-mdv2011.0.i586.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 78d019f5" ; 
this is the error i encounter

Comment: Sorry, you're going to need to figure out the package stuff yourself. For that error, it means you need to import the key for the relevant repo to proceed. Its possible that compiling from source will be easier in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the help! "Invalid command '<Macro', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration" does this error mean the macro hasn't been installed?

Comment: You probably need to activate the module now, something like 'LoadModule macro_module modules/mod_macro.so' should do the trick.